# Is there a way to "apply" a texture mapped with Generated coordinates to a shader?

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I have a sphere-like model shaded with a voronoi (4d) texture that receives generated coordinates. I didn't use UV or object coordinates because I couldn't solve the texture artifacts they produced, and the generated coordinates work fine.

The geometry of the model is extended with a boolean (join operation). The voronoi texture extends perfectly into the new geometry. But, when I try to apply the boolean modifier, the voronoi texture changes.

What I would like to achieve, is to apply the boolean modifier to the sphere-like mesh without changing the way it is textured (I spent a long time tweaking the voronoi to the point where it looked how I wanted it, and it now changing is a big inconvenience).

Is there a way I can "apply" the shading texture first? In a similar way in which I can apply any other modifier, like a deform modifier if I wanted to change the mesh before joining it. Maybe I can "extract" the voronoi texture to its own 3d-image file, then import the file back into the shader? Or can I add a node that "captures" the generated coordinates and retains them after the boolean modifier is applied?

Thank you.

Comment: You could bake the texture?

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Apologies for my low skill level.

Comment: How can I mark the question as solved?

Comment: You can't mark the question as solved. The principle is to have an answer and accept it. In this case, either @moonboots will write an answer or you can do it yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work though, I'm testing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate your object A (object + its boolean object), apply the modifier of object B, unwrap B, give it a material with an *Image Texture* node (use the *Texture Coordinate* UV output this time), select A, shift select B, bake A to B (settings below):

[image]